# Visual Studio Android ListView ItemClick Event no debugging possible

Tags: c#, android, debugging

if I try to debug the ItemClick Event of a ListView I allway get the Message

"No compatible Code running on the thread"

"Unkown Error: 0x80004005"

I think this is happening since VS 17.6.0 but not 100% sure about this. It did work for sure in the past.

The only workaround was to create a custom ListView and create my own click event

ItemClick += MyItemClick;

```
private void MyItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);       
    Action myAction = () =>
    {
        myclickevent(sender, e)
    }
    hander.Post(myAction)
}
```